# How to send param text to url with ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm working on a simple page using Javascript and AngularJs which is composed by two views: home and detail of product. The home is a simple list of products. With the next piece of code i'll send the id obtained by an api:

```
$scope.watchDetail = function(hash){
        $location.path(hash).search({id: $scope.seeMore.Id});
    }
```

and on the detail view i catch the id value with the code:

```
function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    var getId = getUrlVars()["id"];
```

If i need to send also the name of product, per example:

```
$scope.nameProduct = "the_name_of_product_"
```

Before the id to have something like:

```
/the_name_of_product_id
```

How can i do that?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: it would be ideal to use routing such as [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or `ui.router` for this. Then it's enough to pull out url parameters with `$routeParams`

Comment: in fact, i'm using ngRoute. Do you have an example to use $routeParams. Sorry, i'm new using $routeParams

Comment: you can try `.when('/:nameOfProduct/:id'` in your config, and in your controller (after injection) pull out those parameters with `$scope.nameProduct = $routeParams.nameOfProduct` and same for `$routeParams.id`

Comment: Thanx. One last question: i have to use `$location.path(hash).search({id: $scope.seeMore.Id}); ` yet?

Comment: Please limit the question to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.